# Python / Pyspark Indexing and Slicing issue on Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm not entirely sure if I need to index or slice to retrieve elements from an output in Python.

For example, the variable "Ancestor" produces the following output.

```
Out[30]: {'ancestorPath': '/mnt/lake/RAW/Internal/origination/dbo/xpd_opportunitystatushistory/1/Year=2022/Month=11/Day=29/Time=05-11',
 'dfConfig': '{"sparkConfig":{"header":"true"}}',
 'fileFormat': 'SQL'}
```

[image]

The element "xpd_opportunitystatushistory" is a table and I would like to retrieve "xpd_opportunitystatushistory" from the output.

I was thinking of something like:

```
table = Ancestor[:6]
```

But it fails.

Any thoughts?

I have been working on this while waiting for help.

the following

```
Ancestor['ancestorPath']
```

Give me

```
Out[17]: '/mnt/lake/RAW/Internal/origination/dbo/xpd_opportunitystatushistory/1/Year=2022/Month=11/Day=29/Time=05-11'
```

If someone could help with the remaining code to pull out 'xpd_opportunitystatushistory' that would be most helpful

ta

Comment: Can I get your thoughts with this question SO members. I thought this would have been pretty straightforward for members with Python experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Ancestor` is a dictionary (key value pairs) and hence has to be accessed using a key which in this case is `ancestorPath`.
- I have assigned the value similar to yours and was able to retrieve `ancesterPath` as you have figured out.

[image]

- Now to get the `xpd_opportunitystatushistory` you can use the following code. Since the value of Ancestor['ancestorPath'] is a string, you can split and then extract the required value from the resulting array:

```
req_array = Ancestor['ancestorPath'].split("/")
print(req_array)
print(req_array[7])
```

[image]

- If you want to retrieve complete path until `xpd_opportunitystatushistory`, then you can use the following instead:

```
req_array = Ancestor['ancestorPath'].split("/")
print(req_array)
print('/'.join(req_array[:8]))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Saideep, thanks for reaching out. Going to try your suggestion now. I will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Hi @Saideep, I just need  **xpd_opportunitystatushistory**. However, ```req_array = Ancestor['ancestorPath'].split("/")``` gives me ```['', 'mnt', 'lake', 'RAW', 'Internal', 'origination', 'dbo', 'xpd_opportunitystatushistory', '1', 'Year=2022', 'Month=11', 'Day=29', 'Time=05-11']```

Comment: Is there anyway to modify the code such that it just retrieves **xpd_opportunitystatushistory**?

Comment: You can use req_array[7] to get that value directly. To write in a single line it would be `Ancestor['ancestorPath'].split("/")[7]`

Comment: Hi, Saideep, yes I just realised that I can use req_array[7]. Thanks for giving me the single line ```Ancestor['ancestorPath'].split("/")[7]```