# Databricks / Apache Spark PySpark Refactor / Re-code issue

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am using PySpark on Databricks to write data to SQL Database to Schemas OCC and dbo as follows:

```
l_schemas=["OCC"]# list for storing your schemas
l_tables=[table] # list for storing respective tables in that particular indexed schema
for i in range(0,len(l_schemas)):
    s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i] # concatenation and making as schema.table_name
    my_dfone.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
```

and

```
l_schemas=["dbo"]# list for storing your schemas
l_tables=[table] # list for storing respective tables in that particular indexed schema
for i in range(0,len(l_schemas)):
    s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i] # concatenation and making as schema.table_name
    my_dftwo.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
```

It was suggested that I use the following code (which is a lot cleaner)

```
l_schemas=["OCC","dbo","one"]# list for storing your schemas
l_tables=[table] # list for storing respective tables in that particular indexed schema
for i in range(0,len(l_schemas)):
    s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i] # concatenation and making as schema.table_name
    df.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
```

The above would be fine, however I would somehow have to assign **df** to a variable, because I need to execute both **my_dfone** and **my_dftwo**

My code attempt is was as follows:

```
l_schemas=["OCC", "dbo"]# list for storing your schemas
l_tables=[table] # list for storing respective tables in that particular indexed schema

for i in range(0,len(l_schemas)):
    s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i] # concatenation and making as schema.table_name
    my_dfone.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()\
    .my_dftwo.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
```

But it failed.

Can someone therefore let me know how to write the code to SQL Database without having to virtually duplicate the code - basically a lot cleaner

P.S.
**table** is a variable

I also tried the following:

```
l_schemas=["HR", "FPP"]# list for storing your schemas
l_tables= str(table) # list for storing respective tables in that particular indexed schema

for i in range(0,len(l_schemas)):
    s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i] # concatenation and making as schema.table_name
    df_fpp.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
    
    df_hr.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
```

But it failed

I am now trying the following, again with no luck:

```
l_schemas=["FPP","HR"]# list for storing schemas
l_tables=[table, table] # list for storing respective tables in the particular indexed schema

for i in range(0,len(l_schemas)):
    s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i] # concatenation and making as schema.table_name
    df_fpp.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()

for i in range(0,len(l_schemas)):
    s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i] # concatenation and making as schema.table_name
    df_hr.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
```

Update Question,
The following code provided unfortunately does not work

```
table = Ancestor['ancestorPath'].split("/")[7]
l_tables=[table]
l_schemas = ['dbo']
for i in range(0,len(l_tables)):
    s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i] # concatenation and making as schema.table_name
    my_dfone.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
    
    my_dftwo.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
```

I tried to modify the code as follows:

```
table = Ancestor['ancestorPath'].split("/")[7]
l_tables=[table]
l_schemas = ['FPP','HR']
for i in range(0,len(l_tables)):
    s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i] # concatenation and making as schema.table_name
    df_fpp.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
    
    df_hr.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
```

However, it kept on only showing the results for df_hr.write.mode("overwrite")

Comment: hi @Patterson , before `my_dftwo` you are using `.`

Comment: could you please add what error are you getting

Comment: Hi SaiVamsi, thanks for reaching out. I have updated the code a little from .save()\ to just .save\. However, I'm getting the error ```NoneType' object has no attribute 'my_dftwo'``` and error message says ```----> 6     my_mydfone.write.mode("overwrite") \```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I got same error**

[image]

**Note: remove dot(.) before second Dataframe**

As you can Check, Dataframe executed successfully .

**Code:**

```
l_schemas=["dbo", "dbo"]# list for storing your schemas
l_tables=["Persons","db123"] # list for storing respective tables in that particular indexed schema

for i in range(0,len(l_schemas)):
    s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i] # concatenation and making as schema.table_name
    df_one.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
    
    df_two.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
```

[image]

**Update:**

I followed same approach as suggested by saideep

As you can check its working fine:

[image]

**Try this approach**

```
table = Ancestor['ancestorPath'].split("/")[7]
l_tables=[table]
l_schemas = ['dbo']
for i in range(0,len(l_tables)):
    s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i] # concatenation and making as schema.table_name
    df_one.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
    
    df_two.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi SaiVamsi, going to try your suggestion now.. will let you know how I get on thanks

Comment: Hi SaiVamsi, I'm getting the error at line 5 ```s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i]``` The error is ```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "method") to str```

Comment: I think I'm getting the error because I'm using the code ```table = Ancestor['ancestorPath'].split("/")[7]``` which @Saideep helped me with at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74666253/python-pyspark-indexing-and-slicing-issue-on-databricks/74683414?noredirect=1#comment131820123_74683414

Comment: I think I will need to convert the method to a string. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Hi SaiVamsi, I have updated the question using your suggestion, but if failed.

Comment: hi @Patterson, please check the above update.

Comment: Hi @SaiVamsi, unfortunately your update didn't work. I have updated the question with an explaination

Comment: Hi @Patterson, if you executed this code : `table = Ancestor['ancestorPath'].split("/")[7]
l_tables=[table]
l_schemas = ['dbo']
for i in range(0,len(l_tables)):
    print(l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i])` . what output are you getting

Comment: Hi @SaiVamsi, first thanks for sticking with me on this issue. I'm not actually getting an error. The problem is that I'm only getting data from ```df_two.write.mode("overwrite") \``` . I think this is becaue ```df_two.write.mode("overwrite") \``` is overwriting ```df_one.write.mode("overwrite") \```